# Find value in vector "p" that corresponds to maximum value in vector "r = f(p)"

Tags: matlab

As simple as in title. I have *nx1* sized vector `p`. I'm interested in the maximum value of `r = p/foo - floor(p/foo)`, with foo being a scalar, so I just call:

```
max_value = max(p/foo-floor(p/foo))
```

How can I get which value of `p` gave out `max_value`?
I thought about calling:

```
[max_value, max_index] = max(p/foo-floor(p/foo))
```

but soon I realised that `max_index` is pretty useless. I'm sorry asking this,  real beginner here.

---

Having dropped the issue to pieces, I realized there's no unique corrispondence between values `p` and values in my related vector `p/foo-floor(p/foo)`, so there's a logical issue rather than a language one.

However, given my input data, I **know** that the solution is unique. How can I fix this?
I ended up doing:

```
result = p(p/foo-floor(p/foo) == max(p/foo-floor(p/foo)))
```

Looks terrible, so if you know any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the index, use it:

```
result = p(max_index)
```

Comment: Sorry, but max_index should be referred to vector `p/foo-floor(p/foo)`, not `p`. So `p(max_index)` would make no sense, since it's the index of another vector.. am I wrong?

Comment: I think your solution would work only if the function (`p/foo-floor(p/foo)`) has some certain qualities, linearity maybe.

Comment: It's not a question of linearity, but a question of indexing. The solution is the correct answer to your question, assuming that `foo` is a scalar.

Comment: You are right. What I said is probably true if both vectors get sorted in ascending order. Maybe. No matter, thanks!

Comment: You did the hard part, I just indexed an array ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new vector with your lets say "transformed" values:

```
p2 = (p/foo-floor(p/foo))
```

and then just use `find` to find the max values on p2:

```
max_index = find(p2 == max(p2))
```

that will return the index or indices of p2 with the max value of that operation, and finally just lookup the original value in p

```
p(max_index)
```

in 1 line, this is:

```
p(find((p/foo-floor(p/foo) == max((p/foo-floor(p/foo))))))
```

which is basically the same thing you did in the end :)